# Identify Widgets by Row/Column

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Alright, so this question was sort of already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750908/tkinter-identifying-button-by-row-and-column), but I looked through the code and couldn't seem to find where they actually called up the button by its Row/Column, as I am somewhat new to tkinter. This is the code I want:

```
for i in range(10):

    for j in range(10):

        if "" == #the button at the coordinates i,j 's text value :

            counter += 1
```

The problem is, I don't know the actual way of calling it up. Yes, I didn't identify them, as this is a variable Minesweeper application, so that's the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to identify a button based on its row and column location. This means you used `grid()` as the geometry manager and you draw the buttons on some parent widget I am going to call `parent`.

Based on your code and question's statement, you can use [`winfo_children()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) method to loop over the children/buttons  of `parent`  and [`grid_info()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_info-method) to access its children  by `row` and `column` option values.

Here is `identify_button_by_row_and_column()` method that you can modify to fit your actual needs:

```
def identify_button_by_row_and_column(parent, row, column):
    for child in parent.winfo_children():
        info = child.grid_info()                            
        if info['row'] == str(row) and info['column'] == str(column):
            # Do or return something here
```

Comment: Thanks for that well explained answer!